# tsql query - select records from 2 tables without joining them

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 table as follows:

```
emp_id emp_name  emp_add  emp_no dept_name
1      sss       hhh      0      hhh
2      wsss      ddd      0      hhh

2nd table is as follows:
dep_name dept_no
hhh      1
```

I have select records only from `table 1` where `dept_name` matches with the second table. 
I cannot use joins because there are 300 records in table with matches with table 1 records.
and also I want to set the value of `emp_no` in `table 1` as `dept_no` of `table 2`.
Any help?

Comment: Why is 300 records a problem? I'm just trying to understand because a join might still be the best option.

Comment: Why can't you use joins? I would hope that you have matches between the 2 tables, that's the idea. Also why do you have dept_name in the 1st table if you have a semi-normalized setup with the 2nd table that contains dept_name and dept_num?

Comment: Explain your situation more clearly, with relevant example data.  And then explain more clearly what you want from that example data.  I guarantee that if you want related data from two different tables that you'll be doing a join.  You may be doing other things as well (correlated sub-queries, TOP clauses, GROUP BY clauses, etc), but you'll still be doing a join.  Explain the need, then let SO's mutlitudes describe the answers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see absolutely no reason to avoid using a join.

```
UPDATE t1
    SET emp_no = t2.dept_no
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.dept_name = t2.dept_name
```

Comment: This is the obvious answer that we all have in mind, I just hate the idea of having to join on a field that obviously looks like a varchar/nvarchar. I guess you play the hand you're dealt.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
select t1.*, (select top 1 dept_name from table2 t2 where t2.dept_no = t1.dept_no)
from table1 t1
```

Comment: How can I set value of emp_no as dept_no in this?

Comment: That depends. How does table1 refer to table2 in your schema?

Comment: Correlated subqueries are a poor technique and totally unnecessary for this problem.

Comment: Correlated subqueries do have one possible advantage here but you would need to replace `top 1` with `distinct` to get it (error if more than one match)